# Using state in to methods but state isn't updated right away

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-2016

I have a function that makes a call to get a new access token getNewAccessToken() and in the method sets the token in state. Then another method postComment() is called but it doesn't have the correct accessToken in state yet (since the setstate was an async call and probably doesn't have the value yet. What is the best way to fix this to ensure postComment() has the correct state value?

```
  goPost() {
    console.log("In goPost()");
    this.getNewAccessToken();
    this.postComment();
  }
async getNewAccessToken(){
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token`... set up fetch
      );
      if (response.ok) {
         this.setState({
            accessToken: json.access_token
         });
      }
}
async postComment() {
    let accessToken = this.state.accessToken;
}
```

Comment: When the state updates, your component updates. You can check for such change inside of `componentDidMount` so that when your accessToken is set in the state, your component *reacts* to that in the proper lifecycle method. Alternatively (bad idea, but for the sake of learning), `setState` has a callback parameter

Comment: Could you attach a full code of the file, not just a part of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So these are all asynchronous calls, meaning they do not get fired in a predictable order. To make this work, you have to take matters into hand and force the order of execution. In order to do this change, your goPost function should be converted to an async call. Then, it should await the subsequent calls to force a pause to get the token.

```
  async goPost() {
    console.log("In goPost()");
    await this.getRefreshToken();
    this.postComment();
  }
```

So now the this.postComment will not be executed until you receive your token. Also additional note, there is no need to make post comment asynchronous unless you plan to do aync things inside that function.

> Asynchronous programming is a tricky subject! It is good if you can
>   read more on these concepts so that you have a solid footing on the
>   way these things work! Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrNQS8J67zc&t=1269s) to learn more, it helped me a lot!

Comment: In this manner, promises are enforced to work predictably, but the `setState` itself is an asynchronous call which is placed inside the `getRefreshToken`, which may/may not have updated the state when `postComment` is called. 
So I suggest to take `setState` out of the function or pass the `postComment` as callback to the `setState` (as 2nd parameter).

Comment: I changed the code to return the token and I put an await on it. Then I passed the token to postComment(). Passing postComment() as a callback to setstate would also have worked. I thought about moving some code to componentDidUpdate() but just because the token changed I didn't necessarily want to trigger a post. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead inside `postComment`-

1. check if the state has `access_token`, if yes, jump to 3, if no,
2. call the `getNewAccessToken` inside the `postComment` method,
3. extract the `access_token`,
4. call to post a comment using the `access_token`,
5. when successfully done,
6. save the token in the state and
7. when next time, if your call to post a comment fails due to `access_token` expired, call `getNewAccessToken` again (after point 2) and follow the cycle.